# Where to point to Python 3 on OS X?

Tags: macos, python-3.x

I installed python 3.4 on OS X (10.9.5) but can't seem to reference it.

Here's a test file to see what version

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4.3

import sys
print(sys.version)
```

result prints as: `2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)`

i also tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
```

and both return the same thing: `2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)`

not sure what's going on inside the folder `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/` I can see Python 3.4 config files and directories? is this just a place where Python was unzipped, am I still yet to install it or something?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`? Does `python3` start the right version on the command line? What does `which python3` show you?

Comment: How are you executing the script?

Comment: Use `python3` not `python` in a shell command line.

Comment: @jonsharpe, yes python3 from the command line starts up.. Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03)

Comment: when i use, #!/usr/bin/env python3 from a script, still says 2.7.5